# Потоковое обновление Grid

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, sql-server

Делаю многопользовательскую программу для учета. База SQL Server 2008. На главной форме у меня Grid, и как можно сделать чтобы данные в нём, при изменении в базе, сразу обновлялись. По таймеру как то глупо будет. Можно ли сделать как то так:

создать триггер на базе, и при изменение посылать команду какую-нибудь что мол "надо обновить список". Что-то на подобии или совсем другой вариант, главное при изменении таблицы в базе, в программе чтобы сразу обновлялся Grid.

Comment: Нарыл кое-что про MSQL2008 Extended Events, но пока толком не понял что это и с чем едят.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть в эту сторону [Использование уведомлений запросов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175110(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Да это наверно подойдет. А есть пример какой нибудь ?

Comment: Читайте. Это как руководство. Там есть примеры.  
Примеры все, что связано с Service Broker.

Comment: Как то странно. Делал по статье: создал службу, маршрут и очередь. Потом в Студии подключаюсь к серверу и хочу подписаться на уведомление. На что мне выходит ошибка 'Неизвестное имя параметра "WebCacheNotifications" присутствует в идентификаторе параметров уведомления'